# I'm getting error when manipulating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrPge.png)'

## *Erro array.map*

> I'm having problems with the return of this array, when I call it integer no problem, I get the return normally, but when I call by index, for example [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrPge.png) , it would have to return 28 obj, but it's only returning by renaming 5 obj, and I can't find the reason why it's just returning 5''

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  
  const books = [
    ['Intro'],
    [
      [' '],
      [
        'Tiago, servo de Deus, e do Senhor Jesus Cristo, às doze tribos que andam dispersas, saúde.',
      ],
      ['Meus irmãos, tende grande gozo quando cairdes em várias tentações;'],
      ['Sabendo que a prova da vossa fé opera a paciência.'],
      [
        'Tenha, porém, a paciência a sua obra perfeita, para que sejais perfeitos e completos, sem faltar em coisa alguma.',
      ],
      [
        'E, se algum de vós tem falta de sabedoria, peça-a a Deus, que a todos dá liberalmente, e o não lança em rosto, e ser-lhe-á dada.',
      ],
      [
        'Peça-a, porém, com fé, em nada duvidando; porque o que duvida é semelhante à onda do mar, que é levada pelo vento, e lançada de uma para outra parte.',
      ],
      ['Não pense tal homem que receberá do Senhor alguma coisa.'],
      ['O homem de coração dobre é inconstante em todos os seus caminhos.'],
      ['Mas glorie-se o irmão abatido na sua exaltação,'],
      ['E o rico em seu abatimento; porque ele passará como a flor da erva.'],
      [
        'Porque sai o sol com ardor, e a erva seca, e a sua flor cai, e a formosa aparência do seu aspecto perece; assim se murchará também o rico em seus caminhos.',
      ],
      [
        'Bem-aventurado o homem que suporta a tentação; porque, quando for provado, receberá a coroa da vida, a qual o Senhor tem prometido aos que o amam.',
      ],
      [
        'Ninguém, sendo tentado, diga: De Deus sou tentado; porque Deus não pode ser tentado pelo mal, e a ninguém tenta.',
      ],
      [
        'Mas cada um é tentado, quando atraído e engodado pela sua própria concupiscência.',
      ],
      [
        'Depois, havendo a concupiscência concebido, dá à luz o pecado; e o pecado, sendo consumado, gera a morte.',
      ],
      ['Não erreis, meus amados irmãos.'],
      [
        'Toda a boa dádiva e todo o dom perfeito vem do alto, descendo do Pai das luzes, em quem não há mudança nem sombra de variação.',
      ],
      [
        'Segundo a sua vontade, ele nos gerou pela palavra da verdade, para que fôssemos como primícias das suas criaturas.',
      ],
      [
        'Portanto, meus amados irmãos, todo o homem seja pronto para ouvir, tardio para falar, tardio para se irar.',
      ],
      ['Porque a ira do homem não opera a justiça de Deus.'],
      [
        'Por isso, rejeitando toda a imundícia e superfluidade de malícia, recebei com mansidão a palavra em vós enxertada, a qual pode salvar as vossas almas.',
      ],
      [
        'E sede cumpridores da palavra, e não somente ouvintes, enganando-vos com falsos discursos.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque, se alguém é ouvinte da palavra, e não cumpridor, é semelhante ao homem que contempla ao espelho o seu rosto natural;',
      ],
      [
        'Porque se contempla a si mesmo, e vai-se, e logo se esquece de como era.',
      ],
      [
        'Aquele, porém, que atenta bem para a lei perfeita da liberdade, e nisso persevera, não sendo ouvinte esquecidiço, mas fazedor da obra, este tal será bem-aventurado no seu feito.',
      ],
      [
        'Se alguém entre vós cuida ser religioso, e não refreia a sua língua, antes engana o seu coração, a religião desse é vã.',
      ],
      [
        'A religião pura e imaculada para com Deus, o Pai, é esta: Visitar os órfãos e as viúvas nas suas tribulações, e guardar-se da corrupção do mundo.',
      ],
    ],
    [
      [' '],
      [
        'Meus irmãos, não tenhais a fé de nosso Senhor Jesus Cristo, Senhor da glória, em acepção de pessoas.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque, se no vosso ajuntamento entrar algum homem com anel de ouro no dedo, com trajes preciosos, e entrar também algum pobre com sórdido traje,',
      ],
      [
        'E atentardes para o que traz o traje precioso, e lhe disserdes: Assenta-te tu aqui num lugar de honra, e disserdes ao pobre: Tu, fica aí em pé, ou assenta-te abaixo do meu estrado,',
      ],
      [
        'Porventura não fizestes distinção entre vós mesmos, e não vos fizestes juízes de maus pensamentos?',
      ],
      [
        'Ouvi, meus amados irmãos: Porventura não escolheu Deus aos pobres deste mundo para serem ricos na fé, e herdeiros do reino que prometeu aos que o amam?',
      ],
      [
        'Mas vós desonrastes o pobre. Porventura não vos oprimem os ricos, e não vos arrastam aos tribunais?',
      ],
      ['Porventura não blasfemam eles o bom nome que sobre vós foi invocado?'],
      [
        'Todavia, se cumprirdes, conforme a Escritura, a lei real: Amarás a teu próximo como a ti mesmo, bem fazeis.',
      ],
      [
        'Mas, se fazeis acepção de pessoas, cometeis pecado, e sois redargüidos pela lei como transgressores.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque qualquer que guardar toda a lei, e tropeçar em um só ponto, tornou-se culpado de todos.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque aquele que disse: Não cometerás adultério, também disse: Não matarás. Se tu pois não cometeres adultério, mas matares, estás feito transgressor da lei.',
      ],
      [
        'Assim falai, e assim procedei, como devendo ser julgados pela lei da liberdade.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque o juízo será sem misericórdia sobre aquele que não fez misericórdia; e a misericórdia triunfa do juízo.',
      ],
      [
        'Meus irmãos, que aproveita se alguém disser que tem fé, e não tiver as obras? Porventura a fé pode salvá-lo?',
      ],
      [
        'E, se o irmão ou a irmã estiverem nus, e tiverem falta de mantimento quotidiano,',
      ],
      [
        'E algum de vós lhes disser: Ide em paz, aquentai-vos, e fartai-vos; e não lhes derdes as coisas necessárias para o corpo, que proveito virá daí?',
      ],
      ['Assim também a fé, se não tiver as obras, é morta em si mesma.'],
      [
        'Mas dirá alguém: Tu tens a fé, e eu tenho as obras; mostra-me a tua fé sem as tuas obras, e eu te mostrarei a minha fé pelas minhas obras.',
      ],
      [
        'Tu crês que há um só Deus; fazes bem. Também os demônios o crêem, e estremecem.',
      ],
      ['Mas, ó homem vão, queres tu saber que a fé sem as obras é morta?'],
      [
        'Porventura o nosso pai Abraão não foi justificado pelas obras, quando ofereceu sobre o altar o seu filho Isaque?',
      ],
      [
        'Bem vês que a fé cooperou com as suas obras, e que pelas obras a fé foi aperfeiçoada.',
      ],
      [
        'E cumpriu-se a Escritura, que diz: E creu Abraão em Deus, e foi-lhe isso imputado como justiça, e foi chamado o amigo de Deus.',
      ],
      [
        'Vedes então que o homem é justificado pelas obras, e não somente pela fé.',
      ],
      [
        'E de igual modo Raabe, a meretriz, não foi também justificada pelas obras, quando recolheu os emissários, e os despediu por outro caminho?',
      ],
      [
        'Porque, assim como o corpo sem o espírito está morto, assim também a fé sem obras é morta.',
      ],
    ],
    [
      [' '],
      [
        'Meus irmãos, muitos de vós não sejam mestres, sabendo que receberemos mais duro juízo.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque todos tropeçamos em muitas coisas. Se alguém não tropeça em palavra, o tal é perfeito, e poderoso para também refrear todo o corpo.',
      ],
      [
        'Ora, nós pomos freio nas bocas dos cavalos, para que nos obedeçam; e conseguimos dirigir todo o seu corpo.',
      ],
      [
        'Vede também as naus que, sendo tão grandes, e levadas de impetuosos ventos, se viram com um bem pequeno leme para onde quer a vontade daquele que as governa.',
      ],
      [
        'Assim também a língua é um pequeno membro, e gloria-se de grandes coisas. Vede quão grande bosque um pequeno fogo incendeia.',
      ],
      [
        'A língua também é um fogo; como mundo de iniqüidade, a língua está posta entre os nossos membros, e contamina todo o corpo, e inflama o curso da natureza, e é inflamada pelo inferno.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque toda a natureza, tanto de bestas feras como de aves, tanto de répteis como de animais do mar, se amansa e foi domada pela natureza humana;',
      ],
      [
        'Mas nenhum homem pode domar a língua. É um mal que não se pode refrear; está cheia de peçonha mortal.',
      ],
      [
        'Com ela bendizemos a Deus e Pai, e com ela amaldiçoamos os homens, feitos à semelhança de Deus.',
      ],
      [
        'De uma mesma boca procede bênção e maldição. Meus irmãos, não convém que isto se faça assim.',
      ],
      [
        'Porventura deita alguma fonte de um mesmo manancial água doce e água amargosa?',
      ],
      [
        'Meus irmãos, pode também a figueira produzir azeitonas, ou a videira figos? Assim tampouco pode uma fonte dar água salgada e doce.',
      ],
      [
        'Quem dentre vós é sábio e entendido? Mostre pelo seu bom trato as suas obras em mansidão de sabedoria.',
      ],
      [
        'Mas, se tendes amarga inveja, e sentimento faccioso em vosso coração, não vos glorieis, nem mintais contra a verdade.',
      ],
      [
        'Essa não é a sabedoria que vem do alto, mas é terrena, animal e diabólica.',
      ],
      [
        'Porque onde há inveja e espírito faccioso aí há perturbação e toda a obra perversa.',
      ],
      [
        'Mas a sabedoria que do alto vem é, primeiramente pura, depois pacífica, moderada, tratável, cheia de misericórdia e de bons frutos, sem parcialidade, e sem hipocrisia.',
      ],
      ['Ora, o fruto da justiça semeia-se na paz, para os que exercitam a paz.'],
    ],
    [
      [' '],
      [
        'De onde vêm as guerras e pelejas entre vós? Porventura não vêm disto, a saber, dos vossos deleites, que nos vossos membros guerreiam?',
      ],
      [
        'Cobiçais, e nada tendes; matais, e sois invejosos, e nada podeis alcançar; combateis e guerreais, e nada tendes, porque não pedis.',
      ],
      [
        'Pedis, e não recebeis, porque pedis mal, para o gastardes em vossos deleites.',
      ],
      [
        'Adúlteros e adúlteras, não sabeis vós que a amizade do mundo é inimizade contra Deus? Portanto, qualquer que quiser ser amigo do mundo constitui-se inimigo de Deus.',
      ],
      [
        'Ou cuidais vós que em vão diz a Escritura: O Espírito que em nós habita tem ciúmes?',
      ],
      [
        'Antes, ele dá maior graça. Portanto diz: Deus resiste aos soberbos, mas dá graça aos humildes.',
      ],
      ['Sujeitai-vos, pois, a Deus, resisti ao diabo, e ele fugirá de vós.'],
      [
        'Chegai-vos a Deus, e ele se chegará a vós. Alimpai as mãos, pecadores; e, vós de duplo ânimo, purificai os corações.',
      ],
      [
        'Senti as vossas misérias, e lamentai e chorai; converta-se o vosso riso em pranto, e o vosso gozo em tristeza.',
      ],
      ['Humilhai-vos perante o Senhor, e ele vos exaltará.'],
      [
        'Irmãos, não faleis mal uns dos outros. Quem fala mal de um irmão, e julga a seu irmão, fala mal da lei, e julga a lei; e, se tu julgas a lei, já não és observador da lei, mas juiz.',
      ],
      [
        'Há só um legislador que pode salvar e destruir. Tu, porém, quem és, que julgas a outrem?',
      ],
      [
        'Eia agora vós, que dizeis: Hoje, ou amanhã, iremos a tal cidade, e lá passaremos um ano, e contrataremos, e ganharemos;',
      ],
      [
        'Digo-vos que não sabeis o que acontecerá amanhã. Porque, que é a vossa vida? É um vapor que aparece por um pouco, e depois se desvanece.',
      ],
      [
        'Em lugar do que devíeis dizer: Se o Senhor quiser, e se vivermos, faremos isto ou aquilo.',
      ],
      [
        'Mas agora vos gloriais em vossas presunções; toda a glória tal como esta é maligna.',
      ],
      ['Aquele, pois, que sabe fazer o bem e não o faz, comete pecado.'],
    ],
    [
      [' '],
      [
        'Eia, pois, agora vós, ricos, chorai e pranteai, por vossas misérias, que sobre vós hão de vir.',
      ],
      [
        'As vossas riquezas estão apodrecidas, e as vossas vestes estão comidas de traça.',
      ],
      [
        'O vosso ouro e a vossa prata se enferrujaram; e a sua ferrugem dará testemunho contra vós, e comerá como fogo a vossa carne. Entesourastes para os últimos dias.',
      ],
      [
        'Eis que o jornal dos trabalhadores que ceifaram as vossas terras, e que por vós foi diminuído, clama; e os clamores dos que ceifaram entraram nos ouvidos do Senhor dos exércitos.',
      ],
      [
        'Deliciosamente vivestes sobre a terra, e vos deleitastes; cevastes os vossos corações, como num dia de matança.',
      ],
      ['Condenastes e matastes o justo; ele não vos resistiu.'],
      [
        'Sede pois, irmãos, pacientes até à vinda do Senhor. Eis que o lavrador espera o precioso fruto da terra, aguardando-o com paciência, até que receba a chuva temporã e serôdia.',
      ],
      [
        'Sede vós também pacientes, fortalecei os vossos corações; porque já a vinda do Senhor está próxima.',
      ],
      [
        'Irmãos, não vos queixeis uns contra os outros, para que não sejais condenados. Eis que o juiz está à porta.',
      ],
      [
        'Meus irmãos, tomai por exemplo de aflição e paciência os profetas que falaram em nome do Senhor.',
      ],
      [
        'Eis que temos por bem-aventurados os que sofreram. Ouvistes qual foi a paciência de Jó, e vistes o fim que o Senhor lhe deu; porque o Senhor é muito misericordioso e piedoso.',
      ],
      [
        'Mas, sobretudo, meus irmãos, não jureis, nem pelo céu, nem pela terra, nem façais qualquer outro juramento; mas que a vossa palavra seja sim, sim, e não, não; para que não caiais em condenação.',
      ],
      [
        'Está alguém entre vós aflito? Ore. Está alguém contente? Cante louvores.',
      ],
      [
        'Está alguém entre vós doente? Chame os presbíteros da igreja, e orem sobre ele, ungindo-o com azeite em nome do Senhor;',
      ],
      [
        'E a oração da fé salvará o doente, e o Senhor o levantará; e, se houver cometido pecados, ser-lhe-ão perdoados.',
      ],
      [
        'Confessai as vossas culpas uns aos outros, e orai uns pelos outros, para que sareis. A oração feita por um justo pode muito em seus efeitos.',
      ],
      [
        'Elias era homem sujeito às mesmas paixões que nós e, orando, pediu que não chovesse e, por três anos e seis meses, não choveu sobre a terra.',
      ],
      ['E orou outra vez, e o céu deu chuva, e a terra produziu o seu fruto.'],
      [
        'Irmãos, se algum dentre vós se tem desviado da verdade, e alguém o converter,',
      ],
      [
        'Saiba que aquele que fizer converter do erro do seu caminho um pecador, salvará da morte uma alma, e cobrirá uma multidão de pecados.',
      ],
    ],
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {books.map((tg) => (
         console.log(tg[1])
         (<p key={tg}>{tg[1]}</p>)
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: because your `books` array contain only `5` objects

Comment: what are you trying to do with `key={tg[1]}`

Comment: I think you are trying to map over the `books[1]` because it contains `28` elements. So you have to use `books[1].map.......`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was my mistake... now it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.

```
return (
<div>
  {books[1].map((tg, index) => {
     console.log(tg[0])
     return <p key={tg}>{index +1 }- {tg[0]}</p>
  })}
</div>
```

);
);

Comment: Thank you very much, that was my mistake... now it worked

Answer (score 0):

Youre returning an array of array.

To display all data, you need to make sure the value of array is string.

For your case, you might need to flatten the array before loop

1. change your `const books =` into `let books =`
2. below that, or before return statement add this code, to flatten array

```js
  books = [].concat(...[].concat(...books));
```